# Button in div tag

Tags: html, button

I have a div footer and I want to place links to various social media sites in it. Currently I have:

```
<div id="footer">
    <button type="button"
       onclick="href='window.location.https://www.facebook.com'">
       <img class="socimage" src="Facebook_icon.jpg"/></button>
</div>
```

I'm using a regular button tag because off hand that was the easiest way I can think of to also add an image to it and have it set to a css. The problem is the link is not working. I'm sure style wise there is a better way, maybe using forms but I'm a little rusty on html. Also as I stated I want more than one button so if I should use a `form` tag I don't want the link within that tag

Comment: You should avoid using a `button` as an hyperlink. Button semantic is to POST info to the server, while link semantic is to GET. I'd recommend you to modify your markup and use a `<a><img /></a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a regular button tag because off hand that was the easiest way I can think of to also add an image to it and have it set to a css.

It isn't. The easiest way is to use a regular link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img class="socimage" src="Facebook_icon.jpg"></a>
```

> The problem is the link is not working

Your JavaScript is a big syntax error. If you want to use JS to redirect the browser, then you need to *assign* a *string* to `location`:

```
location = "https://www.facebook.com/";
```

Comment: Thank you! Like I said it's been awhile since I have done html, I can't believe I forgot something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You're using it wrong -- the correct way would be:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location = 'https://www.facebook.com'"><img class="socimage" src="Facebook_icon.jpg"/></button>
```

**However**, it would be better to just use an `<a>` tag, just like this:

```
<a href="https://facebook.com"><img class="socimage" src="Facebook_icon.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to use an `a` tag rather than `button`

```
<div id="footer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class="socimage" src="Facebook_icon.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

If you need to keep the button implementation for some reason, there is an error in your `onclick` code. It should be:

```
onclick='location.href="https://www.facebook.com/"'
```